# Text to speech in Arabic

Tags: android

I want to add Arabic language to text speech in my Application but I didn't do it.Where can I find Arabic language for the android application and how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
Svox(Classic Texttospeech) downlaod this app from the Google paly store,for Arabic language this application only give trial period for test our app 15 days ,other apps not given that trail period and after 15 days this svox app will work only, once you get the paid version of Svox and the cost of the application voice is rs.164, for arabic malik voice is there

this is the link for malik voice

--https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.svox.classic.langpack.ar_xa_male_trial

Comment: How can I  adding svox to myApplication?

Comment: First of all you have to install the svox(Classic textto speech) app from the market place then only tou have to install the malik voice for arabic, once you install the svox(Classic textto speech) app then you goto settings->Language & input->Select Text-to-Speech outpot in right side of the screen you will see your svox text tospeech engine and select that engine thats all.                        and you just use normal textto speech syntax it will work frnd and if this answer is usefull put accepted answer or put upvote for me friend

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

1-Download the iSpeech-SDK-1.3.9-SampleApp.zip

2-import the iSpeech-SDK-1.3.9-sampleApp Project into Eclipse

3-Double click on the AndroidManifest.xml file. Modify the value of "apikey" metadata to the iSpeech API Key you obtained from 
[enter link description here](http://www.ispeech.org/developers/.)

from Ispeech.org

Comment: it works okay with english text 
what about with other text can you provide any info/example