# How i can convert Arabic text to speech in an Android app?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, arabic-support

**I am trying to convert Arabic text to speech in my app but it seems that the current Android TTS does not support the Arabic language? Is there  any way I can do to To support Arabic speech in my app**

when I set Language **UK it works ok**

```
textTospeech.setLanguage(locale.UK);
```

but when to change Language to **Arabic it not Get the speech text**

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
textTospeech.setLanguage(locale);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771430/how-to-use-android-tts-in-arabic , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525166/text-to-speech-in-arabic , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851384/arabic-tts-text-to-speech-library-for-android , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019995/how-to-convert-arabic-text-to-speech-in-an-android-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Android TTS in Arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771430/how-to-use-android-tts-in-arabic)